# Looking for starter code for my eslint rule

Tags: javascript, eslint

I'd like to write an eslint rule that reports a warning whenever the sort() method of an Array object is called.

Can somebody point me to some starter code? Is there an existing rule that I can clone and modify to make this rule?

Thanks,

-E

Answer (score 0):

Eslint have a very well [written documentation with a lot of code](http://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/working-with-rules) to get your stated.